# Integrating with Simpsons rule

Tags: integration

I have been given the task of calculating the integral $\int_0^2\ e^{x^2} dx$ using Simpsons rule, $S(f) = (b-a)/6(f(a)+4f((a+b)/2) +f(b))$. When calculated I get the integral to be approximately 22.2. Now, the value of the integral is approximately 16.5 which makes the approximation very far from the exact value. Is my calculation incorrect?

Comment: You may need to break the interval of integration into several subintervals and apply Simpsons rule to each to get a better approximation.

Comment: You´re right, @JohnColeman.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is alright when subinterval space, $h=\Delta x=1$.

When $h=0.5$ then we get:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
x&0&0.5&1&1.5&2\\ \hline
f(x)&1&e^{0.25}&e&e^{2.25}&e^4
\end{array}
$$
By applying [Simpson’s 1/3 Rule of Integration](http://w3.gazi.edu.tr/~balbasi/mws_gen_int_txt_simpson13.pdf) we get:  $$\int_0^2f(x)\ dx=\dfrac{0.5}{3}\left[1+e^4+4(e^{0.25}+e^{2.25})+2e\right]\approx17.35.$$

> When $h=0.25$ then we get:
>   $$
> \begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
> x&0&0.25&0.5&0.75&1&1.25&1.5&1.75&2\\ \hline
> f(x)&1&e^{0.0625}&e^{0.25}&e^{0.5625}&e&e^{1.5625}&e^{2.25}&e^{3.0625}&e^4
> \end{array}
> $$
>   So now by applying [Simpson’s 1/3 Rule of Integration](http://w3.gazi.edu.tr/~balbasi/mws_gen_int_txt_simpson13.pdf) we get: $$\int_0^2f(x)\ dx=\dfrac{0.25}{3}\left[1+e^4+4(e^{0.0625}+e^{0.5625}+e^{1.5625}+e^{3.0625})+2(e^{0.25}+e+e^{2.25})\right]\approx16.54.$$

Comment: It'd probably make it more clear what's going on in the sums if you wrote the terms out sequentially rather than grouping by coefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Simpson's rule works by dividing the integration interval into smaller segments, then approximating the function by drawing a parabola through the function values at the endpoints and middle of each segment. Generally, the smaller the segments, the better the approximation. For example, if you take the entire interval as a single segment (as you did), the approximation looks like this

[image: One-segment approximation]

(Blue is actual, yellow is approximate) Now that's not very good at all, is it? No wonder you're getting a bad answer. But suppose we divide into four segments instead. Now the approximation looks like this.

[image: Four-segment approximation]

That's tons better. The last interval is a little wonky, but the others are so close you can barely tell there's another line. In fact, the error in the integral will decrease as the fourth power of the segment width. k.Vijay's answer gives the actual numbers showing the rapid decrease in the error term as the segment width decreases.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

take $n $, even,  for example 10,100,..
Compute
$$S_i=\frac {1}{3n}(f (i/n)+4f ((i+1)/n)+f ((i+2)/n)) $$
for $i=0,2,4,...2n-2$
and sum.

Answer (score 0):

No, the calculation is not incorrect. Using a quadratic interpolation the formula

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx \frac{b-a}{6}\left(f(a)+4f\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)+f(b)\right)$$

becomes

$$\int_0^2 e^{x^2} dx \approx \frac{2-0}{6}(1+4e+e^4) \approx 22.157$$

We get closer when using the result of a cubic interpolation ([Simpson's $\dfrac{3}{8}$ rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Simpson.27s_3.2F8_rule)):

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx \frac{b-a}{8}\left(f(a)+3f\left(\frac{2a+b}{3}\right)+3f\left(\frac{a+2b}{3}\right)+f(b)\right)$$

$$\int_0^2 e^{x^2} dx \approx \frac{2-0}{8}(1+3e^{\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2}+3e^{\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)^2}+e^4) \approx 19.5,$$

which is about twice as accurate as your previous calculation.